# Why is UIView drawRect causing first pass of UIScrollview to be choppy/jerky/slow?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, uiscrollview, uiimageview

EDIT: It looks like the problem code is in a procedural background that I am drawing in a UIView which I am then adding as a subview to UIScrollView. The procedural code is below. It draws box shapes, which look sort of like a skyline. Any Ideas why this is slowing down the first pass of my UIScrollView? It can be as much as a thousand pixels wide or more at times. See image...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
UIBezierPath *vertLine = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

[vertLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,self.frame.size.height)];

int detail = 10;
int ranNum = 0;
int count = self.bounds.size.width/detail;
CGFloat heightIncrement = 0.0;

CGFloat minHeight = self.frame.size.height;

CGFloat xPos = 0;
CGFloat yPos = self.frame.size.height-20;

for (int i =0; i<count; i++)
{
    ranNum += (arc4random() % 9)-5;

    yPos -= (arc4random() % 30);
    [vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos,yPos)];

    xPos += (arc4random() % 20)+10;
    [vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos,yPos)];

    yPos += (arc4random() % 30);
    [vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos,yPos)];

    xPos += (arc4random() % 30);
    [vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos,yPos)];

    if (yPos>self.frame.size.height-10) {
        yPos = self.frame.size.height-10;
    }

    if (yPos<self.frame.size.height-50) {
        yPos = self.frame.size.height-50;
    }

}

[vertLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(count*20,(self.frame.size.height))];

[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:38.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255 alpha:1] setFill];

[vertLine fill];

}
```

[image: Procedural background drawn in drawRect causing slow UIScrollView]

<strike>I have a jerky scroll view, but ONLY on the first pass. After all the views have been viewed in the scroll view, it is very smooth.</strike>

First Pass: During the first pass it appears that when each UIImageView is coming into view (from right to left) There is a jerk right when it is entering the visible area. So if you reference the attached image, you'll see UIImageView 5 entering from right to left. When this happens there is a small pause as if the scroll view is telling the image view to load/prepare to be on stage. I have tried to profile this but I don't see any problems in my code and im not sure how I can profile the methods etc. that I have not overridden. So a sub question would be... What methods are called on a subview of UIScrollView when it is entering the visible area?

As I mention I tried to do the async and other concurrent approaches, but it seems that no matter how the images are loaded, the first pass is always jerky, then its as if the UIScrollView caches the subviews. Is it possible to do this caching/loading up front... 
[scrollView cacheSubViews]; I would rather have a slower startup than it to be clunky on the first scroll.

Thanks for any ideas on this or information about how the UIScrollView works with its subviews. I have seen many questions and some solutions about jerky UIScrollViews with UIImageViews as subviews. I have tried many of them, but still have a slow scrollview.

austin

Comment: Can you put up the code please?

Comment: Alright, let me build a sample... But its just UIImageViews in a UIScrollView...

Comment: This is definitely because you are downloading images and displaying in uiimageviews synchronously.I think you are downloading images from server. You should download images in background and then using main thread you should UI(ie display images in tableview). One of the sample I got from net: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: Thanks – nikhita dkslfslg You helped me find the problem, its my procedural background. So its not the images at all but a subclass of UIView that I am using drawRect to draw in. Anyone know why this is so slow in UIScrollView but only on the first pass?

Answer (score 0):

`imageWithContentsOfFile` is a synchronous process takes a lot of tile.Use some asynchronous way to load the images and the smoothness can be achieved